# I can't quit properly my apps if I use mysql connection

Tags: qt

If I do not use connection I can properly exit.

In Pdv.h file

```
namespace Pdv {
    ...
    extern QSqlDatabase db;
    ...
}
```

In LoginDialog.cpp file

```
QSqlDatabase Pdv::db;
...
    Pdv::db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL3");
    Pdv::db.setHostName(Pdv::DB_URL);
    Pdv::db.setUserName(Pdv::DB_USER);
    Pdv::db.setPassword(Pdv::DB_PASS);
    Pdv::db.setDatabaseName(Pdv::DB_DB);
    if(!Pdv::db.open()) {
    ...
    // Checking user login/password and retrieve many variables
...
```

In mainwindow.cpp file

```
...
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
...
    if(Pdv::db.isOpen()) {
        qDebug() << "Opened 1";
        Pdv::db.close();
        qDebug() << Pdv::db.lastError();
        if(Pdv::db.isOpen())
            qDebug() << "Opened 2";
    }
    Pdv::app->quit(); // or QApplication::quit();
}
```

I got this error in QTCreator console

```
Opened 1
QSqlError("", "", "")
Le programme s'est terminé subitement.
/home/cosmic/src/build-Pdv-Desktop-Debug/Pdv crashed.
```

A idea?

Comment: close your connection in your app's shutdown sequence?

Comment: Pdv::db.close(); does not close it ?

Comment: I don't know qt, but maybe `Pdv::db.open()` reopens the database.

Comment: but you re-open it again right away afterwards, so you've effectively done nothing

Comment: You are right, if I use one close () I have the same problement crash. I edit theanswer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make proper exit with usage of QSqlDatabase, you need preferably:

1. remove all instances of QSqlDatabase objects (because as you copy them, they will keep connection open).
2. As second condition, you need to use QSqlDatabe::removeDatabase() call. (also this call will make qDebug message if database is still in use occasionally - some QSqlDatabase object is left somewhere - it will help to identify a problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you close and delete your `MainWindow`, and your program then crashes, then other parts of the program must be trying to use the `MainWindow` pointer even though it is destroyed.

I think the problem is the line of code `Pdv::app->quit();` Try with `QApplication::quit();` instead or review the code in `Pdv::app->quit();`.

Comment: I try with your suggestion, same error :( And if I not connect I can quit properly. So I think that's the connection that is the problem.